# What is the best way to loop through a unknown size string array?

Tags: c#, loops

I want to loop through a string array let's say 
    string elements= "item1, item2, item3";

what is the best way to loop and get each item in that array into their own separate variable? I also want to be able to loop a string array that is unknown in the number of items in the array as well. Any help would be appreciated. My code below fails as soon as a string i use have more than three items, lets say 4 or 5 items in the string.

```
public void getString(string anyString)
{ 
            foreach (var element in elements.Where(el => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(el)))
            {

                if (element == "item1")
                {
                    string gotTheElement = element;
                    myOtherMethod(gotTheElement);
                    if (element == "item2")
                    {
                        string gotTheElement2 = element;
                        myOtherMethod(gotTheElement);
                    }
                    if (element == "item3")
                    {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
            }
}


public void myOtherMethod(string anyString)
{
 //do whatever with the string you got.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will attempt to answer this based off of pulling teeth in the comments, and I'm still not 100% sure if this is even what you are after, but are you after something like this?

**Changes**

1. Input parameter is an array so you can actually iterate over it
2. If statements are properly aligned and not nested

---

```
    public void getString(string[] anyString)
    { 
        foreach (var element in anyString.Where(el => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(el)))
        {
            if (element == "item1")
            {
                myOtherMethod(element);
            }
            else if (element == "item2")
            {
                myOtherMethod(element);
            }
            else if (element == "item3")
            {
                myOtherMethod(element);
            }
        }
    }


    public void myOtherMethod(string anyString)
    {
         //do whatever with the string you got.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll have a stab at it, it this what you want to do?

**Edit:**
added a counter to test if every item in the array was handled

```
    public string GetString(string anyString)
    {
        var elements = anyString.Split(',');
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var element in elements.Where(element => element.Contains("item"))) {
            switch (element)
            {
                case "item1": //do something
                    count++;
                    break;
                case "item2": //something else
                    count++;
                    break;
                default:
                    return "unknow element";

            }
        }
        return elements.Count() != count ? "not all elements was handled? or unknown elements with not 'item' string got passed" : "done?";
    }
```

**Edit (again)**

In my efforts to try and understand what you are trying to do I went to your profile and I see you had similar responses to this question and you tried to ask the same question a few times. You need to take a step back and ask your self one question first. Are you writing `server-side` or `client-side` code.

- **`Server Side`**: like your example are code to create web-pages
- **`Client Side`**: are code like JavaScript that happens on the page (on the browser - hence the word client side ie at the client;

You cannot expect to pass html strings of objects on your page (`client`) then use it (`server side`) to do something with it again on the `client`. I think you should possibly explain better what you are trying to do with these "item" strings? Right?